# what is the difference between jax-rpc and jax-ws web services?

Tags: java, jax-ws, jax-rpc

what is the difference between jax-rpc and jax-ws web services?

How to migrate legacy code using jax-rpc to jax-ws?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13758/migrate.htm#WSGET259  
Migration guide.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main difference between JAX-RPC and JAX-WS is the programming model. A JAX-WS based service uses annotations (such @WebService) to declare webservice endpoints. Use of these annotations obviates the need for deployment descriptors. With JAX-WS, you can have a webservice deployed on a Java EE compliant application server without a single deployment descriptor. Apart from these, other additional features (such asynchronous callbacks etc) are also present.

To migrate your PRC base project to WS you need to follow below steps -

1. Analyse the existing code implemented with RPC.
2. Change herds and make it compatible to WS header.
3. change existing client or write new client.
4. You don't see any difference between payload request and response . you should test all your bdd to make sure migration is successful.